# mod_rewrite: transform = and & in slashes

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I was just looking for a solution to transform any =,?,& found in a query string into a simple slash /.
To be more specific, my link is something like:

http://www.mydomain.com/product.php?c=1&sc=12&products_id=15

and I would it like this:
http://www.mydomain.com/product.php/c/1/sc/12/products_id/15

whatever the master page could be (in this case is product.php, but it could be foo.php, bar.php...or else).
I have googled a lot but didn't find any good solution to achieve what i'm looking for.
I have found complex rewrite rules, but they all include the "page name" into them:
i.e.

*RewriteRule ^/?index/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /index.php?foo=$1&bar=$2 [L,QSA]*

That rule is only applicable to index.php and to known variables like foo, bar.
I need a more general one, whatever the master page is, whatever the variables are.
Can this be done?

Any suggestion?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're using apache >= 2.2. Add this to your apache conf:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # you absolutely need to use RewriteBase if this snippet is in .htaccess
    # if the .htaccess file is located in a subdirectory, use
    # RewriteBase /path/to/subdir
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(=|&)*([^=&]+)(=|&)?(.*?)=*$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/%2?%4= [N,NE]

    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^=$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?  [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

The first RewriteCond/RewriteRule pair repeatedly matches a token delimited by & or = and adds it to the path. The important flag is the [N] that causes the whole ruleset to start over again, as often as the rule matches. Additionally, a = is appended to the end of the query string. This is to create a mark in the URL that at least one rewrite has happened.

The second ruleset checks for the = mark that remains after the URL has been rewritten completely and issues a redirect.

Have a look at http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString for some useful hints.

Comment: Thanks Marcellus, your snippet almost made the trick! :) 
What I get is:
http://www.mydomain.com/web/htdocs/www.mydomain.com/home/product.php/c/1/sc/12/products_id/181

as you can see it takes also the web server directories web/htdocs/www.mydomain.com/home/
that shouldn't be there.

Any hint?

Comment: I had that behaviour too when I added the snippet to a .htaccess file. It seems to add the file path to the relative URL. The snippet worked flawlessly when I added it to httpd.conf / httpd-vhosts.conf. Do you have access to your .conf files?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't. Any other way to succeed without touching the httpd.conf?

Comment: I have improved the answer and added a comment. You need to use RewriteBase / which should make it work.